# Ubuntu server 20.04 will not automatically reconnect to internet after an internet outage or by unplugging the ethernet cable

Tags: networking, server, internet, ethernet

Using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server connected to the internet via Ethernet cable.

When my internet service provider has an outage I have to restart my server to regain internet access.

All my other devices seem to reconnect just fine via WiFi.

What could be the problem?

I also just tried unplugging the Ethernet cable manually and  plugging it back in and the same behavior happens.

I don’t have internet and need to restart the server. Thanks.

**Edit:** I have found out that the use of my VPN is causing DNS issues. I am using Mullvad VPN via its CLI and have internet connection on bootup up until any internet disconnection be it physcially by unpluging the internet or ISP outage. I can ping 8.8.8.8 after the fact but not google.com. I think the VPN has issues with the systemd-resolved service. Again, I have no issues when I deactivate the VPN.

Comment: What does "connected to the Internet" mean, here? Do you mean it is directly-connected to your provider's device?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need a new DHCP lease.

You can refresh this in a few ways, here are two simple ones:

- from the command line, do: `sudo service network-manager restart`
- from the desktop, go to the Network Manager, disable and then re-enable networking.